# what part is ambigous? im trying to append to a dataframe within a dictionary using the date (timezone aware)for an index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, ambiguous

im using a .loc to find the row and just append straight in.....it just speeds things up, because the bigger the dataframe gets, the longer append tends to take. that is also the reason im using dictionairies. so i basically wrote this code to make the row create itself, and fill the data its missing with in, with the data it has in the list, within the dictionary(i've also tried a list, no dictionary, to append, basically same problems

```
data['googl'].loc['{}'.format(tempdata.keys())] = data['googl'].append(tempdata[rawclock],ignore_index=True) 


ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

if you need any variables defined. I'll be glad to do so

Comment: The question title should be a short summary of your problem, not contain code or be the only question. Please read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: updated....,any ideas on how to fix it?